# Repositories and Better Array Usage with Querying DB

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel User's Repository that I am utilizing but to prevent the always nagging N+1 problem I'm trying to get all my users to be returned with their role and status in the user's array.

As you can see right now with how its running I have 200+ times its running because of how any records in my db I have. So I"m trying to cut that down.

How would I go about doing this?

```
<?php namespace Backstage\Repositories\Users;

use User;
use Backstage\Repositories\DbRepository;

class DbUserRepository extends DbRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface {

    protected $model;

    function __construct(User $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

views/users/partials/table.blade.php

```
<td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->full_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->email_address }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->role->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->status->name }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eager loading to get rid of the N+1 problem, see the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)

You didn't include your models so not 100% sure about naming, but i think you need this:

```
function __construct(User $model)
{
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->model->load('roles');
}
```

However this always eager loads the roles for the DbUserRepository. 
You can also call ->load('roles') in the right method only.